# how do I fix this imported model

Tags: objects

[image: Models are messed Up]

I've been struggling on importing models in blender because most of the models that I imported are like this. How do I fix them. Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: what, exactly is wrong, how should it look imported, what are we looking at?

Comment: it should be a kitchen but I don't know how to rearrange the objects in this imported model. most of the models that I downloaded are like this straight up IKEA and I don't know how to fix it Im new in blender btw . thanks

Comment: are you able to share the file you imported from, what file format was it?

Comment: Its in 3ds format. and as I have observe There's a center point in all the object so how can I set all the points in the center btw it's in a group something I d'ont really understand because I'm new to blender

Comment: No problem. The hierarchy of objects is important. It does look like all the objects are parented to an object (That is named DUMMYGroup but is not a true Blender Group). If you move/rotate/scale the DUMMYGroup then all the child objects will get affected. If you select and move/rotate/scale one of the individual objects then only that object will be affected. You can have object parent hierarchies of many levels and you can remove the parent with ALT+p.